# Can't create new app on itunesconnect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have some issue while creating a new app on iTunesConnect; when I click on the "+", it's not opening the scroll menu. No error in the console, I've contacted Apple, but no answers.
Is it only me with this problem?

Comment: Have you tried multiple web browsers?

Comment: Which browser you are using? Use Safari

Comment: Safari and chrome, and i've tried on my mac but also on  my ipad

Comment: I have the same issue on Firefox as well. It looks like the menu associated to the + button has a lower layer that the apps list and goes below

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had the same issue. There was an update on the contract / license agreement to review and approve (I had an advice on the iTunes connect main page). I did it. Then I came back to iTunes connect and now I can add a new app.

You may need to logount / login again after approving the new license agreement.

Comment: When logging in to the member center, I had to make sure I went into my personal account, and not my organization's account, in order to find license agreement to accept.  Also, I had to log out and back into iTunes Connect, but this was my issue as well.  Thanks.

Comment: Would be nice by Apple to show an actual error message when clicking the "+" instead of making it look like a CSS bug...

Comment: I have the same issue. I accepted the agreement. I tried safari and chrome. I logged out and back into Member Center and iTunesConnect several times. Still no luck. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For me, the problem was that my last version was "Developer Rejected", since I had cancelled the submission. I had to delete the old build from that version and add a new uploaded build, and then I could save it (with a new public version number if I wanted) and submit it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you, and what worked for me was deleting the cache files from the [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com) page.

I don't know why they are having this annoying bug of not showing any modals after clicking the `+` button; but I guess it has something to do with CSS or the Angular app that runs inside this page.

Comment: This worked for me as well. I was able to add new versions while in chrome's incognito mode. I just cleared Chrome's cached data and it works now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it seems that apple is having a css bug when clicking the + sign (it doesn't show any message).
The solution is to activate the certificate from the "Member Center" atdeveloper.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

My version was on 'Prepare for Submission' as I was using test-flight with some testers. I deleted the build from my app version and updated the build there.

Answer (score 0):

I had just activated Two Factor Authentication, logging out and in again fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and in my case it was due to the version number. Apple enforces a rule that version numbers must be in ascending order, however there is no error message when an invalid version number is entered, the new version is simply not created.

The version numbers are not parsed as decimals, but as strings of integers.

In my case the previous version was "2.11" and I wanted to create a new version "2.2". That failed because 2 < 11, even though 2.2 > 2.11

Edit: I may have also had a previous version "2.2", so that could have been the problem rather than any ordering. In any case, an invalid version number can definitely be the cause of this.